# Symfony2 Entity form Field with two entities

Tags: php, forms, symfony, entity

I want to make a select dropdown in my form that contains 2 entities.

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder(new VisitEvent())
     ->add('date', 'text')
     ->add('where', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'PGMainBundle:Field',
                'property' => 'name',
     )
)
```

I'd like to use two entities at once in the dropdown. What I've got here is just one of them the second one would be Simulator. I'd like to know what approach I should take.

merge the two entities into an array and pass it to a choice field instead?

Or is there a better way to use it with the entity field?

Comment: When you say two entities at once, how do you mean? What are you looking to do?

Comment: a dropdown with both Fields and Simulators combined.
Also from different classes

Comment: you should depend on some interface and pass to form one array collection (combined fields and simulators)

Comment: I need something similar, I want to select items from two different entities, fe: in my entity Blog, one field could select items from Product and Promos entities. I would like to know how implement this. thanks